# MySQL Unique Index and NULL Values

Tags: mysql

Here's the quandary that has racked my brain all day.

The Amazon Orders API consists of [ListOrders](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/orders-2013-09-01/Orders_ListOrders.html) and [ListOrderItems](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/orders-2013-09-01/Orders_ListOrderItems.html).

`ListOrders` provides `AmazonOrderId`'s that are then used as input in `ListOrderItems` to provide additional information about the Order.

The issue is that an `AmazonOrderId` is not a unique identifier. This rules out adding a `UNIQUE KEY` to this column.

The actual unique identifier is `OrderItemId` which is retrieved from `ListOrderItems` with the `AmazonOrderId`.

Right now I have a `UNIQUE INDEX` set for both the `AmazonOrderId` and `OrderItemId`.

```
. . . .
UNIQUE KEY `unique_orders_index` (`AmazonOrderId`,`OrderItemId`)
```

The issue is, when I'm inputting `AmazonOrderId` rows from `ListOrders`, I need `AmazonOrderId` to act as a `UNIQUE KEY`, and cause a duplicate error message on insertion.

This is allowing for duplicate `AmazonOrderId` rows if double-passed in `ListOrders`.

At this point, my unique identifier `OrderItemId` is `NULL` (because it has not yet been retrieved from `ListOrderItems`.

Only when calling `ListOrderItems` with a specific `AmazonOrderId` will I know if there are multiple orders (or `OrderItemId`'s) in the same `AmazonOrderId`, and then conditionally add the additional duplicate `AmazonOrderId` if this is the case.

Is there any way I can work this so that for sure only one unique `AmazonOrderId` row value is inserted if `OrderItemId` is (as it must be in my `ListOrders` `INSERT`/call) `NULL`?

Comment: As `NULL=NULL` is `NULL`, it fails to be blocked by uniqueness checking and duplicates can be inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AmazonOrderId is probably unique - *per order* - but not in a list of order items. The normal way to store the info would be in two tables, one for the orders, and another for the order items. The later would have a foreign key to the orders table.

You would then get and store the order in it's table. After that, you retrieve the order item(s) and store them in their table.

If you feel you must store the info in a single table, then default the orderitemid to a value that is not going to be a value value, such as -1 or 0. When you have an order item id to insert, just check for that special value and do an update instead of an insert.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Initial testing of putting the default value to `-1` prevented duplicate initial `AmazonOrderId`'s.  I am just doing an `UPDATE` in `ListOrderItems` so this seems like it will work!  As for the additional tables and foreign keys, I'll have to rethink about this later on as I optimize!